# Maximum of continuous function on non-compact domain

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, nonlinear-optimization, maxima-minima

The extreme value theorem
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem
states that a continuous functions $f: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ must attain a maximum (and minimum) on $\Omega$ if $\Omega$ is compact.
This is not necessarily the case on non-compact (e.g. open) domains.

I wonder wether there is theory on the existence of maxima of continuous functions on non-compact domains $\Omega$.
I can only think of *somehow* proving that the minimum has to be inside a compact subset $\hat{\Omega} \subset \Omega$. But probably there are more sophisticated theorems?

Thanks!

Comment: If you loose hypothesis on $\Omega$ you need to add them to the function $f$. For example, if you have a compactly supported function the results still holds. But this is an oversimplified case, maybe there are  more interesting results.

Comment: A common argument when $\Omega$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is that if function goes to infinity as it approaches the boundary of $\Omega$, then it has a minimum on $\Omega$. You could probably generalize this to locally compact topological spaces.